# If $Y_n$ are random variables and $Y_n \to Y_\infty$ a.s. and $G$ is an open set, then $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} 1_G(Y_n) \geq 1_G(Y_\infty)$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

From Rick Durret's book "Probability: Theory and Examples," 5th edition, chapter 3, on Theorem 3.2.11 in the course of proving that if $X_n$ are random variables converging weakly to $X_\infty$, then for all open sets $G$, $\lim \inf \mathbb P(X_n \in G) \geq \mathbb P(X_\infty \in G)$, he mentions the following:

> Let $Y_n$ have the same distribution as $X_n$ and $Y_n \to Y_\infty$ almost surely. Since $G$ is open, $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} 1_G(Y_n) \geq 1_G(Y_\infty)$.

However, I am having trouble understanding why this has to be true, and why the fact that $G$ is open has anything to do with this.

Comment: Just consider the cases when RHS is $0$  and when RHS is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega_{0}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid Y_{n}(\omega)\rightarrow Y_{\infty}(\omega)\}$.
By assumption, $P(\Omega_{0})=1$. Let $\omega\in\Omega_{0}$. If
$Y_{\infty}(\omega)\notin G$, we have that $1_{G}(Y_{\infty}(\omega))=0$.
Since $1_{G}(Y_{n}(\omega))\geq0$ for each $n$, it follows that
$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}1_{G}(Y_{n}(\omega))\geq1_{G}(Y_{\infty}(\infty))$.
If $Y_{\infty}(\omega)\in G$, then there exists $N$ such that $Y_{n}(\omega)\in G$
whenever $n\geq N$ (because $G$ is open and $Y_{n}(\omega)\rightarrow Y_{\infty}(\omega)$).
Hence, for each $n\geq N$, $\inf_{k\geq n}1_{G}(Y_{k}(\omega))=1$
because $1_{G}(Y_{k}(\omega))=1$ for each $k\geq n$. It follows
that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}1_{G}(Y_{n}(\omega))=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf_{k\geq n}1_{G}(Y_{k}(\omega))=1=1_{G}(Y_{\infty}(\omega))$.

This shows that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}1_{G}(Y_{n})\geq1_{G}(Y_{\infty})$
on $\Omega_{0}$.